# Reset Bootcamp To Factory Setting

Tags: bootcamp, windows

I would like to know if there is a way to reset the apple application Bootcamp Assistant to its factory settings.
I changed the info.plist into the wrong configuration and I cannot reverse it back.

Comment: Someone might be willing to provide you will either the file or contents, but you would have to provide more information.